# How to properly set routes to assign roles to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Let's say I have a '**Member**' and a '**Project**' models.

'**Member**' and '**Model**' reflect a many to many association and are linked through a project_members join table.

Any member can take a role that may not be the same across all the projects associated to her.

I'm trying to write an '**add_role**' and a '**remove_role**' method to assign roles to members.

Since roles should be assigned per project/member I've built a controller 'project_members_controller' where I could write those methods.

What I'm confused though is that given the way I'm defining the routes for those methods I'm getting two POST routes with the same path. Therefore, it sounds like I'm doing something wrong or not understanding how Rails works.

**Currently my routes are defined as:**

```
resources :projects do
  member do
    get "collaborators", to: "members/members#index"
    post "collaborators/:id/set_role", to: "project_members#set_role"
    post "collaborators/:id/remove_role", to: "project_members#remove_role"
  end
end
```

**Translated in the following routes:**

```
               Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                           Controller#Action
collaborators_project GET    /projects/:id/collaborators(.:format)                 members/members#index
                      POST   /projects/:id/collaborators/:id/set_role(.:format)    project_members#set_role
                      POST   /projects/:id/collaborators/:id/remove_role(.:format) project_members#remove_role
             projects GET    /projects(.:format)                                   projects#index
                      POST   /projects(.:format)                                   projects#create
          new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                               projects#new
         edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)                          projects#edit
              project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)                               projects#show
                      PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)                               projects#update
                      PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)                               projects#update
                      DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)                               projects#destroy
```

The URI pattern is what I'm aiming for but does this sound like good practice?

How can I reach the add_role and remove_role methods with a link_to if they share the same path. Should I just chunk a url in the helper? and...

Is it correct to use POST when doing something like this or should I use PATCH?

I'd appreciate your guidance.

**As a reference my 'project_members_controller.rb' contains something like:**

```
def set_role
  @project = params[:project_id]
  if @project.owner.id == current_member.id
    @project_member = ProjectMember.where(project_id: @project.id, member_id: params[:id])
    @project_member.add_role(:observer) if self.roles.blank?
    # CODE RENDERING OUTPUT
    render html: "<h1>HOLA</h1>"
  else
    # CODE THROWIGN AN ERROR
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use RESTful Rails routes

You can change your routes to following

Update 1:

```
resources :projects do
  member do
    get "collaborators", to: "members/members#index"
  end
  resources :collaborators, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Update 2:

```
resources :projects do
  member do
    get "collaborators", to: "members/members#index"
  end
  resources :collaborators, only: [] do
    member do
      post 'set_role', => 'project_members#set_role'
      post 'remove_role' => "project_members#remove_role"
    end
  end
end
```

Update 3:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :collaborators, only: [] do
    get '/' => "members/members#index", on: :collection
    member do
      post 'set_role' => 'project_members#set_role'
      post 'remove_role' => "project_members#remove_role"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I see but what happens in the case where the controller is not available. In this case the Rolify controllers are hidden. In this case RESTful routes won't be enough as I'm in another controller right?

Comment: You are in which controller?

Comment: As per my question above I'm adding those methods in the project_members_controller.rb' only because there's no 'roles_controller.rb' because all Roles are managed by Rolify Gem.
 
I'm thinking maybe I should create a Roles controller and do RESTFul there as you suggested. However, I'm concerned that this would break the gem.

Comment: Thanks Ashvin, your solution does add a path for the route. However, I've get the following URI 
`/projects/:id/collaborators/:id/set_role(.:format)`
and I was expecting something like
`/projects/:community_id/collaborators/:id/set_role(.:format)`
where the first param is :community_id and params[:id] corresponds the collaborator_id.
Is there any way to achieve that

Comment: URI should be `/projects/:project_id/collaborators/:id/set_role(.:format)` as from Update 2

Comment: I see, I made a mistake where I nested your code but no is resulting in that URI. 
One more thing, if you don't mind. Could I simplify by getting rid of the first of the member block and just do something like:
`resources :projects do
  resources :collaborators, only: [:index] do
    member do
      post 'set_role', => 'project_members#set_role'
      post 'remove_role' => "project_members#remove_role"
    end
  end
end`
If this is possible how can I set the index route to go to: `members/members#index` and not search for an inexistent collaborators controller

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having separate methode to add and remove role, you can write a common method `manage_roles` for adding/deleting the role.

**Modify you routes file.**

```
resources :projects do
  member do
    get "collaborators", to: "members/members#index"
    post "collaborators/:id/manage_roles", to: "project_members#manage_roles"
  end
end
```

You can pass a param with the click of link on the basis of which you can identify to add or delete a role.

```
<%= link_to "Add Role", <manage_roles path> , {role_action: 'add_role', method: :post} %>
```

**In your controller, add the `manage_roles` method**

```
def manage_roles
   if param[:role_action] == add_role
     # LOGIC TO ADD ROLE
   else
     # LOGIC TO REMOVE ROLE
   end
end
```

Comment: Pramod, thanks for you answer. I'm probably doing this with one method indeed but my question about the duplicated path remains. In that any POST request I'd like to make to that controller will share the same path with, in your example manage_roles method.

Comment: @Andrew, It's correct to use POST here as you are creating a role for a member.